# What's the most efficient way to access 2D seismic data

Tags: ocean

Can anyone tell me the most efficient/performant method to access 2D seismic data using Ocean?

For example, if I need to perform a calculation using data from 3x2D seismic lines (all with the same geometry) is this the most efficient way?

```
for (int j = 0; j < seismicLine1.NumSamplesJK.I; j++)
{
  ITrace trace1 = seismicLine1.GetTrace(j);
  ITrace trace2 = seismicLine2.GetTrace(j);
  ITrace trace3 = seismicLine3.GetTrace(j);

  for (int k = 0; k < seismicLine1.NumSamplesJK.J; k++)
  {
    double sum = trace1[k] + trace2[k] + trace3[k];
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A followup to @Keith's suggestion - with .NET4 his code could be refactored to a generic:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> TuplesFrom<T1,T2,T3>(IEnumerable<T1> s1, IEnumerable<T2> s2, IEnumerable<T3> s3)
{
  bool m1, m2, m3; // "more" flags
  using (var e1 = s1.GetEnumerator())
  using (var e2 = s2.GetEnumerator())
  using (var e3 = s3.GetEnumerator())
    while ((m1 = e1.MoveNext()) && 
           (m2 = e2.MoveNext()) && 
           (m3 = e3.MoveNext()))
      yield return Tuple.Create(e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current);
  if (m1 || m2 || m3)
    throw new ArgumentException(); // sequences of unequal lengths
}
```

Which gives:

```
foreach (var traceTuple in TuplesFrom(seismicLine1.Traces, seismicLine2.Traces, seismicLine3.Traces))
  for (int k = 0; k < maxK; ++k)
    sum = traceTuple.Item1[k] + traceTuple.Item2[k] + traceTuple.Item3[k];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work except for the two bugs I see, but it can also be made slightly faster. First the bugs. Your loops should be testing NumSamplesIJK.J not .I for the outer loop and .K, not .J for the inner loop. The .I is always 0 for 2D lines.

You can get a slight performance lift by minimizing the dereference of the NumSamplesIJK properties. Since the geometries are the same you should create a pair of variables for the J and K properties and use them.

```
int maxJ = seismicLine1.NumSamplesIJK.J;
int maxK = seismicLine1.NumsamplesIJK.K;
for (int j = 0; j < maxJ; j++)
   ...
   for (int k = 0; k < maxK; k++)
   ...
```

You might also consider using the Traces enumerator instead of calling GetTrace. It will process the data in trace ascending order. Unfortunatley with three lines the code is a bit harder to read.

```
int maxK = SeismicLine1.NumSamplesIJK.K;
IEnumerator line2Traces = seismicLine2.Traces.GetEnumerator();
ITrace line2Trace = line2Traces.MoveNext();
IEnumerator line3Traces = seismicLine3.Traces.GetEnumerator();
ITrace line3Trace = line3Traces.MoveNext();
foreach (ITrace line1Trace in seismicLine1.Traces)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < maxK; k++)
    {
        double sum = line1Trace[k] + line2Trace[k] + line3Trace[k];

    }
    line2Trace = line2Traces.MoveNext();
    line3Trace = line3Traces.MoveNext();
}
```

I don't know what, if any, performance lift this might provide. You'll have to profile it to find out.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate using MoveNext rather than direct trace access.

Comment: SeismicLine2D defines NumSamplesJK (where .I->"J/trace index" and .J->"K/sample index"), not NumSamplesIJK.  No bugs. :-)